# The word for "den" as in a fox's den?

Tags: words

We all know that a fox is a 狐 (kitsune). But what's the word for the burrow/den that a 狐 lives in? This one is stumping the translation tools and old fashioned paper dictionaries I've got my hands on.

Comment: I didn't know before trying to find out from your question, so this shouldn't be taken as certain, but the Japanese Wikipedia article uses the word 巣穴. Just wanted to share my technique, though someone with a better grasp on the language can confirm or deny.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most commonly, it would be:

> 「狐{きつね}の穴{あな}」 or
>
> 「狐の巣{す}」

for us native speakers.

(Far) less common would include:

> 「狐の巣穴{すあな}」
>
> 「狐のねぐら」

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Leebo is right. I don't know about fox specific dens, but [巣穴]{すあな} is usually used for mammals' burrows or nests in holes in the ground, which in concept at least, applies to foxes (mammals who make burrows/nests in the ground).